# unable to install Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader pear

Tags: php, pear

how to install pear reader. i have pear writer and it is working fine, i want to install pear reader

> pear install Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader

```
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader"
install failed
```

What is the exact command to install excel reader in pear

Comment: there is no "reader". there's "spreadsheet_excel_writer", which is abandoned/obsolete library. Try http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ instead, which is modern/in-devel and supports the new OOXML formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader` package on pear.php.net.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was the right way to install Reader:

```
cd /usr/share/pear/Spreadsheet/Excel && mkdir Reader && cd Reader
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/phpexcelreader/Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader/Interim%20update/phpExcelReader.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fphpexcelreader%2F&ts=1396451889&use_mirror=skylink
unzip phpExcelReader.zip
mv ./reader.php ../Reader.php
mv oleread.inc OLERead.php
```